# I'm getting this exception : Unresolved compilation problems

Tags: java

I get this exception after i removed from my project the jars (pdfbox ,bouncycastle etc) and moved them to another folder but i included them in the build path ...

at the first line eclipse shows this error( ***the constructor PDFParser(InputStream) refers to missing type InputStream***) -altought FileInputStream is extended from InputStream- and i don't know why?

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(in);
PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
parser.parse();
String text = textStripper.getText(new PDDocument(parser.getDocument()));
```

any ideas?
**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The constructor PDFParser(InputStream) refers to the missing type InputStream
 The constructor PDFTextStripper() refers to the missing type IOException
 The method parse() from the type PDFParser refers to the missing type IOException
 The method getText(PDDocument) from the type PDFTextStripper refers to the missing type IOException
 The method getDocument() from the type PDFParser refers to the missing type IOException
 The method getDocument() from the type PDFParser refers to the missing type IOException
 The method close() from the type COSDocument refers to the missing type IOException
```

**

Comment: Note that Eclipse has an "incremental compiler" so some (most) of your code may already be compiled while some bits are not.

Comment: its a very good ideea ill try to complie the hole project from scratch. thank u

Answer (score 9):

That just means your project hasn't compiled, but you've still tried to run it. Eclipse lets you do that, only failing when you first try to call something which didn't compile properly.

Look at the compilation errors in your project to track down the real problem. It does seem odd that it can't find `InputStream`: did you remove a bunch of import statements from your code at the same time?

Comment: Thank u for ur response.No, i just moved the jars to another folder and the add them in the build path... it doesnt show any errors in the import area

Comment: @Stephan: Well, ignore the import area but look at the Errors view - I'm pretty sure you'll see something there.

Comment: yes it is and i've posted it : on the line PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(in); it shows me this error "the constructor PDFParser(InputStream) refers to missing type InputStream" this is the first error

Answer (score 1):

You may try a refresh on the project along with clean within eclipse (Project > Clean > All).

Greetz,
GHad

Comment: @Stephan - did you try both suggestions?

Comment: I think this answer is close. I had the same problem but it was with a class that was part of another project in the same workspace. I my case Policy. I did Ctrl-T and opened the class. When I opened it, it said te file is out of sync with the filesystem. I did a refresh on the file after opening it and all was well. Just a clean, rebuild all did not do the trick for me either.

Answer (score 1):

A "missing type" error means the corresponding type is not found in the build path. InputStream would be in the JRE classpath container. Did you remove the JRE classpath container or might it be referring to a wrong location?

The [second hit](http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2009/06/eclipse-build-errors-javalangobject.html) when searching for

> "missing type" inputstream

on google might also be helpful.

Comment: i thought of that and i checked and its on the build path (JRE System Library JavaSE-1.6)

Comment: Have you tried readding it, like the blog I linked to suggests?

Comment: i reloaded the jre library with no success... anyway thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is trying to tell you that the referenced type is "missing" in the class type you are using. Imagine you have Class A, B, and C, where B references C as a field variable; while say, invoking B.setC() in class A, you will see the "refers to missing type" error, if C cannot be reached by B. So check B to see if (1) B is compiled OK, and the imported C is in compile/build path.